# Create a hybrid image [Nginx + perl + node]

Tags: python, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I want to create an image which contains Nginx + perl + node but in doing so I am running into a issues where I see that it cant find python. It works with the nginx:1.15 alpine perl image. Any help would be appreciated.

```
FROM nginx:1.19.8-alpine-perl

ENV NODE_VERSION 10.15.1

RUN addgroup -g 1000 node \
    && adduser -u 1000 -G node -s /bin/sh -D node \
    && apk add --no-cache \
        libstdc++ \
    #&& apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
    && apk --no-cache --virtual build-dependencies add \
        binutils-gold \
        curl \
        g++ \
        gcc \
        gnupg \
        libgcc \
        linux-headers \
        make \
        python \   #This line gives error
    #&& apk add --update --no-cache python2 && ln -sf python2 /usr/bin/python \
  # gpg keys listed at https://github.com/nodejs/node#release-keys
  && for key in \
    94AE36675C464D64BAFA68DD7434390BDBE9B9C5 \
    FD3A5288F042B6850C66B31F09FE44734EB7990E \
    71DCFD284A79C3B38668286BC97EC7A07EDE3FC1 \
    DD8F2338BAE7501E3DD5AC78C273792F7D83545D \
    C4F0DFFF4E8C1A8236409D08E73BC641CC11F4C8 \
    B9AE9905FFD7803F25714661B63B535A4C206CA9 \
    77984A986EBC2AA786BC0F66B01FBB92821C587A \
    8FCCA13FEF1D0C2E91008E09770F7A9A5AE15600 \
    4ED778F539E3634C779C87C6D7062848A1AB005C \
    A48C2BEE680E841632CD4E44F07496B3EB3C1762 \
    B9E2F5981AA6E0CD28160D9FF13993A75599653C \
  ; do \
    gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys "$key" || \
    gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://ipv4.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$key" || \
    gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-keys "$key" ; \
  done \
    && curl -fsSLO --compressed "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/node-v$NODE_VERSION.tar.xz" \
    && curl -fsSLO --compressed "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/SHASUMS256.txt.asc" \
    && gpg --batch --decrypt --output SHASUMS256.txt SHASUMS256.txt.asc \
    && grep " node-v$NODE_VERSION.tar.xz\$" SHASUMS256.txt | sha256sum -c - \
    && tar -xf "node-v$NODE_VERSION.tar.xz" \
    && cd "node-v$NODE_VERSION" \
    && ./configure \
    && make -j$(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN) \
    && make install \
    && apk del .build-deps \
    && cd .. \
    && rm -Rf "node-v$NODE_VERSION" \
    && rm "node-v$NODE_VERSION.tar.xz" SHASUMS256.txt.asc SHASUMS256.txt
```

Comment: *"I am running into a issues where I see that it cant find python"* : What error message do you get? Which line in the `Dockerfile` is failing?

Comment: @HåkonHægland, it's the first ```RUN``` command where I am adding ```python /```. I have made an update to the question to point out the line

Answer (score 0):

Python 2 on Alpine is provided by the [`python2`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.13/community/x86_64/python2) package.

Previously, the package was indeed named `python` (as opposed to [`python3`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.13/main/x86_64/python3)), but it has been [changed](https://git.alpinelinux.org/aports/commit/?h=3.12-stable&id=5ad0ec7da1064361cc74d56edf7524960f49ef9b) in Alpine 3.12.

Quoting Alpine 3.12 [release notes](https://alpinelinux.org/posts/Alpine-3.12.0-released.html):

> There is no longer a python package providing python2. You need to explicitly install python2 or python3. Additionally, as part of the ongoing work to remove python2, many python2 modules have been removed.

Since Python 2 support on Alpine is being gradually removed, consider shifting towards Python 3, if possible.